# is there any way to control the order of joins in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

currently the order is A left join B on ... left join C on ...

I want to add a column to B and C that is not present in A

is there a way to join B and C first including this join condition?

Comment: Left joins are typically resolved later in the execution tree. Please include the complete SQL query.

Comment: If you would like to add a calculated column, then you would do that in the select list, not in the from clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN acts also as hidden STRAIGHT_JOIN, so the tables scanning order matches to their order in the FROM clause of the query text.

If you want join B to C firstly then you may set the joining order with parenthesis. For example, use not

```
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B on A.col1=B.col2
LEFT JOIN C on B.col3=C.col4
```

but

```
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
              B
    LEFT JOIN C on B.col3=C.col4
    )  on A.col1=B.col2
```

or even (MySQL allows this syntax)

```
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
              B
    LEFT JOIN C
    )  on A.col1=B.col2 AND B.col3=C.col4
```

You may also adjust the tables scanning order with [Join-Order Optimizer Hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html).